# How to improve the URL query and format it as per the best practice?

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, filter, encoding

I am setting up a variable, that represents the query. The query itself is more or less hard coded as a String, pulling DOM information in the placeholders.

Client-Side-js.js

```
async function filterMovie(e){
    try {
        const queryAddon = `?title=${titleDOM.value}&genre=${genreDOM.value}&publishDateDOM=${publishDateDOM.value}&limit=${limitDOM.value}&skip=${skipDOM.value}&sort=${sortDOM.value}`
        let data = await fetch(`${baseURL}/movie/filter${queryAddon}`);
        data = await data.json();
        console.log(data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)

    }
}
```

movie-controller.js

```
const showOneMovie = async(req,res)=>{
    try {
        const {title, publishDate, genre, limit, skip, sort} = req.query;
        let data = await Movie.find({title, publishDate, genre}).limit(limit).skip(skip).sort(sort)
        res.status(200).json(data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

Since I am not very familiar with the query part of URLs I have the following questions:

1. The current filters look for the exact values and disregard search params, that are partially inside of the result records. What is best practice when setting up such "startsWith" or "in" operators and how to implement?
2. I have heard that URLs have to be encoded. What happens if I let my String be as it is? What could possibly go wrong? How woud I have to encode it in this example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to send the query params and ensure correct encoding is by using [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) like so:

```js
async function filterMovie(e){
    try {
        const queryAddon = new URLSearchParams({
           title: titleDOM.value,
           genre: genreDOM.value,
           publishDate: publishDateDOM.value,
           limit: limitDOM.value,
           skip: skipDOM.value,
           sort: sortDOM.value
        });
        const response = await fetch(baseURL + '/movie/filter?' + queryAddon);
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

If you then want to do a pattern match similar to an SQL `LIKE` or `IN` query you can use [$regex](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) or [$in](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#-in-expressions)

A `$regex` in mongoose would look like:

```js
const showOneMovie = async(req,res)=>{
    try {
        const {title, publishDate, genre, limit, skip, sort} = req.query;
        //The query below would find any Movie that starts with whatever 
        //is in the title variable, the 'i' means case insensitive
        let data = await Movie.find({ title: { $regex: new RegExp(`\^${title}`), $options: 'i' } }).limit(limit).skip(skip).sort(sort)
        res.status(200).json(data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: That helps a lot! The URLSearchParams method is so much better than simply putting it into a String.

Comment: You can pass keys and values to the `URLSearchParams` constructor as an array of arrays or as one long string (like the one you originally created in `queryAddon`) but adopting the object literal syntax is probably the most semantic. Not sure why your question was closed but does seem a bit broad. Maybe break it down into several smaller questions to solve a particular problem next time. Good luck with your project.